# Android viruses infected my phone (Tecno)

Tags: virus

My phone has been infected with viruses for nearly a year. At first it was just a virus in disguise called 'settings', but then it spread to my Chrome, opening a site called 'aiboo.com' SmartSite. I had to disable Chrome, and now there are 3 other viruses on my phone: One called Magic, which pops up ads on my phone screen, Lake worth ISD or something, Then one called System with the note saying 'Guerilla exe.' I use Eset Mobile Security to remove them, but every time I get access to internet, they get installed again. Sometimes they get installed even if I don't have network connection.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do get a virus, you could perform a factory reset to get rid of it, but that means you’d lose all your data. Your photos, saved games, text messages, and everything else will be gone if you didn’t back them up. Obviously, a factory reset should be your last option.

There are also other malware removal tools without factory reset:
* Malwarebytes
* Bitdefender Antivirus Free

Answer (score 0):

You can use NoRoot Firewall for preventing malware activities such as this.

If the malware appears as an app, then you can use Advanced Task Manager app to uninstall the apps you don't recognise.